# WP CLI not outputting anything

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to use `wp cli` command line tool, but like many others it doesn't work for me.

The site itself is loading with no issues.

getting info does work:

```
$ wp cli info
OS:     Linux 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php7.4
PHP version:    7.4.3
php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:       /home/ubuntu/data/amigo/backup-1.13.2021_04-37-48_amigoco/homedir/public_html
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
```

But any other command just returns blank

I managed to run in debug mode, and it seems to be stuck at some part. Even tried with no plugins and no theme options, but still didn't work:

```
$ wp --debug --skip-plugins --skip-themes user list
Debug (bootstrap): Fallback autoloader paths: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/autoload.php (0.016s)
Debug (bootstrap): Loading detected autoloader: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/autoload.php (0.017s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cache (0.023s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: transient (0.025s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: comment (0.027s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in comment Namespace (0.028s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: menu (0.029s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: item in menu Namespace (0.03s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: location in menu Namespace (0.03s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: network meta (0.031s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: option (0.032s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: post (0.033s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in post Namespace (0.034s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: term in post Namespace (0.035s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: post-type (0.035s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: site (0.037s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in site Namespace (0.038s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: option in site Namespace (0.039s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: taxonomy (0.039s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: term (0.041s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in term Namespace (0.041s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: user (0.044s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in user Namespace (0.045s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: session in user Namespace (0.045s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: term in user Namespace (0.046s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: network (0.046s)
Debug (hooks): Processing hook "after_add_command:network" with 1 callbacks (0.046s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:network": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.046s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in network Namespace (0.047s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: db (0.05s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: plugin (0.055s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: theme (0.057s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: mod in theme Namespace (0.057s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: scaffold (0.06s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: core (0.06s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: verify-checksums in core Namespace (0.061s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: verify-checksums in plugin Namespace (0.061s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: export (0.063s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: config (0.065s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: core (0.068s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: eval (0.069s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: eval-file (0.069s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: import (0.07s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: media (0.073s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: package (0.075s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cron (0.076s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: event in cron Namespace (0.077s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: schedule in cron Namespace (0.077s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: embed (0.077s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: fetch in embed Namespace (0.078s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: provider in embed Namespace (0.079s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: handler in embed Namespace (0.079s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cache in embed Namespace (0.079s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: i18n (0.08s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: make-pot in i18n Namespace (0.082s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: make-json in i18n Namespace (0.082s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: language core (0.084s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: language plugin (0.084s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: language theme (0.085s)
Debug (hooks): Immediately invoking on passed hook "after_add_command:site": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/language-command/language-command.php at line 39 (0.085s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: switch-language in site Namespace (0.086s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: language (0.086s)
Debug (hooks): Processing hook "after_add_command:language" with 3 callbacks (0.086s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:language": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.086s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: core in language Namespace (0.086s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:language": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.086s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: plugin in language Namespace (0.087s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:language": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.087s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: theme in language Namespace (0.087s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: maintenance-mode (0.088s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: rewrite (0.089s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: rewrite (0.089s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cap (0.09s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: role (0.091s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: search-replace (0.094s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: server (0.094s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: shell (0.095s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: super-admin (0.095s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: widget (0.097s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: sidebar (0.097s)
Debug (bootstrap): Adding framework command: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/commands/cli.php (0.097s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cli (0.1s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cache in cli Namespace (0.1s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: alias in cli Namespace (0.101s)
Debug (bootstrap): Adding framework command: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/commands/help.php (0.101s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: help (0.102s)
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.102s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.102s)
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /usr/local/bin/wp --debug --skip-plugins --skip-themes user list (0.102s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /home/ubuntu/data/mysite/backup-1.13.2021_04-37-48_mysiteco/homedir/public_html/ (0.102s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.103s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /home/ubuntu/data/mysite/backup-1.13.2021_04-37-48_mysiteco/homedir/public_html/wp-config.php (0.103s)
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Does anything show up in your PHP error log? There's an issue where [WP-CLI doesn't always display error output](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3220), so you may need to check your logs to see any PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Problem was solved by changing the Database password as it had some `'`-characters.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265667)

Answer (score -1):

This is due to not proper installing of wp CLI uninstall the old one and install it again.
https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/

Comment: Are you sure? See `wp cli info` that I posted in the question. The version is 2.4.0, so it is the latest version.

Comment: @justadev If I understand, it is not about the version but about the method it was installed with.

Comment: It's just a single file. How can you install it wrong?